# Linux syscalls: advantage of copy_file_range over sendfile?

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

I understand that classically, the Linux Kernel was conservative about adding new syscalls.

But, I've learned about the existence of `copy_file_range`, which seems to do the exact same thing as `sendfile`. The only differences I could spot are:

- doesn't work on sockets at all, only on proper regular files
- allows for both input and output offset to be set

But for regular files, a `seek` might achieve the same offset semantics, so now I'm confused what the purpose of the `copy_file_range` syscall is, if its abilities are a strict subset of San existing syscall? Especially since seeking as a separate thing can be done quite sensibly separately, so to not extend the time spent in kernelspace even further l. (As a usual is OS design goal is to make operating system calls not block, and physical seeking can be finished while control is already handed back to userland.)

Comment: https://lwn.net/Articles/637965/ (also its parent article), and also: https://lwn.net/Articles/846403/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`copy_file_range`’s advantage over `sendfile` (and `splice`) is that, in some circumstances, it implements copy offload. In fact that’s its main purpose, and it comes from long-standing work [on copy offload](https://lwn.net/Articles/592094/) — the intention was to provide access to features allowing block copies to be delegated to hardware (*e.g.* SANs). That work is [still ongoing](https://lwn.net/Articles/935260/); currently, copy offload relies on file system support, where copies can either be replaced by a reference in the file system, or delegated to a server. (See [Copy on write for directories?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/702552/86440) for details.)

`sendfile` on the other hand comes from a desire to send files to the network efficiently; similarly, `splice` sends files to pipes efficiently. `sendfile` was extended to send files to other files a long time ago (using `splice` under the hood), but the assumption remains that it’s an optimised read-write: instead of reading data in user-space, and writing it, a process can ask the kernel to take care of the read-write loop.

I suspect that `copy_file_range`’s existence is tied to the additional output offset argument: if you think about exposing a low-level offloading block copy feature available in hardware, tying that to a file descriptor-based API requires both offsets; while that would be possible using `sendfile` and whatever the current offset on the output file descriptor is, perhaps that isn’t tightly-coupled enough for the copy offload objective.

([The generic `copy_file_range` implementation](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.7.6/source/fs/read_write.c#L1386), used on file systems without specific support, delegates to `splice` in [the same way as `sendfile`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.7.6/source/fs/read_write.c#L1254). Arguably `sendfile` could be made to use `copy_file_range` where possible, I don’t know whether that’s ever been implemented.)

Comment: Now that is interesting! Wouldn't have guessed it's about offloading!

Comment: Yeah I think I see the advantage: if you are say a block storage layer and might have a lot of concurrent things to copy, then you either need to serialize (seek, sendfile, seek, send file...) or start dup'ing fds, just to be able to work on multiple fronts. And then the kernel would need to make sure access order guarantees (I assume sendfile had similar semantics as write when it comes to determinism when it returns), and then send out commands to the hardware. Much easier if commands are just "fire and forget" and can be issued from arbitrary many threads in parallel